# Altium - Board Shape does not appear when I generate a pdf pcb print joboutput document

Tags: pcb, altium

I'm using altium design summer 09. When I try to print the pcb to check the pcb size, I noticed that pcb shape did not appear in the pdf. If the keepout layer is selected,, I can have an idea, but if I exclude the keepout layer from the outputjob configuration I can't know the shape of the pcb in pdf. Does someone know why this happens ?

Below are the layers that appear in the document output configuration

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the board shape on a mechanical layer and include it in the outjob.

Answer (score 0):

You should draw the board outline on a mechanical layer and include that layer in your .pdf printouts.

The copper board layers do not normally include the board outline because anything drawn on those layers will produce copper on the board.

Comment: Which mechanical layer I need to use?

Comment: It is a long time since I used Altium (and Altium may have changed a lot since then).  I don't recall if there was a layer specifically assigned for board outline - any unused mechanical layer should do.